# Puerto serial cambia cuando subo un programa a placa Arduino

Tags: arduino

he tenido un detalle al momento de querer subir mis programas a mi placa de Arduino Leonardo, cuando subo mi programa el puerto cambia por ejemplo si era el ttyACM0 cambia al ttyACM1 y por ese motivo no me deja subir mis progrmas, estoy trabajando con debian 10  y la ultima version de arduino para linux, la tarjeta funciona sin problemas en windows 10 donde he trabajando anteriormente, cuando subo el programa deja de reconocerlo por un momento y luego lo vuelve a reconocer pero ya con otro nombre, espero y alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias por aca les dejo una captura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trabajo con Linux Mint, con Arduinos UNO, mini, nano, ESP8266, ESP32 y Wemos. El puerto es siempre el mismo para una misma placa. Sólo varia entre ttyUSB0 y ttyACM0 dependiendo de que placa es.

Comment: si, lo que pasa aqui es que cada vez que intento subir un archivo empieza con el puerto serial /ttyACM0 cuando esta por subirse se reinicia y cambia al /ttyACM1 y asi  respectivamente,